# MDX query quidance

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an MDX query that needs to display result based on a CASE statement. I have written the below query, the query is not throwing any error neither is it giving out any result.

How can I get the query correct?

Query:

```
SELECT NULL ON 0,
CASE 
WHEN [MARKET BASE].[Market Base].[Market Base].&[1] = "Vitamin C (04D1+04D2)"
THEN "Vitamin C (04D1 + 04D2)" END ON 1
FROM [PharmaTrend Monthly Ext]
WHERE [PRODUCT].[Company - Product - Pack].[Company].&[2991]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.SomeValue AS
    CASE 
    WHEN [MARKET BASE].[Market Base].[Market Base].&[1] IS 
            [MARKET BASE].[Market Base].[Market Base].[Vitamin C (04D1+04D2)]
    THEN "Vitamin C (04D1 + 04D2)" 
    END


SELECT 
Measures.SomeValue ON 0
FROM [SomeCube]
WHERE [PRODUCT].[Company - Product - Pack].[Company].&[2991]
```

Comment: seems a bit strange that this works? How will this query display "Vitamin C (04D1 + 04D2)" ?

Comment: Same member being invoked by using the key value and name value.

Comment: surely if this is TRUE `[MARKET BASE].[Market Base].[Market Base].&[1] IS 
            [MARKET BASE].[Market Base].[Market Base].[Vitamin C (04D1+04D2)]` then where-ever you use `Measures.SomeValue` it will always say `"Vitamin C (04D1 + 04D2)" ` ... so what is the point of the CASE?

Comment: I agree..I didn't have the answer with `CASE` construct in mind, just wanted to clarify that in this case, instead of `=`, we should use `IS`

Comment: @YousufSultan Any reason why it as unaccepted as the answer?

Comment: @SouravA - It got unaccepted because I had mistook it be working as initially I just one Market Base available in the cube.. But later after the cube refresh happened, more markets came and the result as exactly the same as told by whytheq... it was repeating the same value for each of them

Comment: That's bad manners! You can't expect the person answering to understand your cube structure or the possible scenarios in advance. It was your mistake that you weren't clear enough with your question. I pointed you in the right direction, you have to take it forward. I don't care about the extra 15 points, but their are certain norms that are followed on this site. Anyway, hope you get your solution soon.